Which scholars say Salat (nafl/fard) isnt restricted to this world only
Quran 51:56 says the mankind and jinn have only been created for worship.
A human/jinn passes through four stages in his entirety.

Alame arwah( the soul world)
Earth.
Barzakh.
Paradise.

There are reports which explicitly say prophets worship in graves. Prophet moses worshipping in grave. [1]  And reports which hint there is voluntary salat in paradise. The wife of umar bin al khattab doing ablution [2].
Additionally the presence of prophet ibrahim near bayt al mamur hints he was doing tawaf of bayt al mamur or praying in its direction. [3] Externally evidenced by action of prophet moses praying in grave.
Based on above, which scholars say the prayer, voluntary/obligatory transcends the life on earth and the verse of Quran 51:56 isnt restricted to worship on earth
[1] Anas ibn Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “I passed by Moses during my night journey near the red mound; he was praying in his grave.”
Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2375
[2] Suddenly I saw a woman performing ablution beside a palace. I asked, "For whom is this palace?" They (the angels) replied, "It is for 'Umar bin Al-Khattab." (Bukhari 3242 and Muslim)
[3] When the Holy Prophet ﷺ reached the seventh heaven on the Night of Ascension, he saw Holy Prophet Ibrahim (علیہ السلام) reclining with his back on Al-Bait-ul-Ma` mur (Tafsir ibn kathir verse 52:4-5)
